# How do I create a detached mock with closure in Spock framework?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

It's good to see we can have [detached mocks](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/427) since Spock 1.1, especially if we want to create a mock utilities for boilerplate UT coding.

But it seems DetachedMockFactory refuses to be initialised with closure.

```
class MockUtils {
    def mockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()

    IRequestContextGetter mockDefaultRequestContext() {
        return mockFactory.Mock(IRequestContextGetter) {
            tenant >> Constants.TENANT
            currencyType >> CurrencyEnum.SGD
        }
    }
}
```

It throws the following error:

> 'Mock' in 'spock.mock.DetachedMockFactory' cannot be applied to
> '(java.lang.Class<com.bytedance.cg.gcrm.salesplanning.common.utils.requestcontext.IRequestContextGetter>,
> groovy.lang.Closure)'

How do I create a detached mock with closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

Longer answer, in Spock mock interactions are actually part of the specification, not the mock object itself. So, detached mocks can't have any interactions until they get attached to a specification.

There is a way, but it is quite cumbersome. You can define you own [IDefaultResponse](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#ALaCarteMocks) to handle the mock interactions and customize your response that way.

```
import org.spockframework.util.*
import org.spockframework.mock.*
import spock.mock.*
    
interface Foo {
    String getBar()
}

class CustomResponse implements IDefaultResponse {
    public Object respond(IMockInvocation invocation) {
        'foo'
    }
}

def factory = new DetachedMockFactory()
def stub = factory.Stub(Foo, defaultResponse: new CustomResponse())
assert stub.bar == 'foo'
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_3_0&codez=eJx1kMFOwzAMhu95Ct_WItQHQOoFpkk9TEjsCdLUKWFNXCUOE0J7d5yuFO2AT7H_378-x_mZIgPFsUkzmbON2uOF4rnJ7KbmQbl_DV66P8Mi_s5ASrnAGK02CAci-F6GJ44ujDAiP-tY1eqqlJl0SvCSE5N_Q4kJCUFCJ_QYOEG3R6vzxJt2S5pzPzkDr_0HGoa4iEPVHQWgC59kNDsK4LZnve6V2lmi3dJdC8GAFoSTKX5BCwEvsEfW5h2Hkna4KQJbfIlzL6bV3pykreS8RxjuKZ-WnPurqrpWciuW35K9ptcR2nalURtdqR84z4fA)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful and informative! If that's the case, then it seems creating a reusable configured mocks is not originally intended in Spock. I still do not know what the valid use case for detached mocks then.

Comment: DetachedMocks are intended for use in dependency injection frameworks that need a way to create and inject mocks outside of the specification. However, all interaction logic would still be inside the specification after the mocks get attached to it.

Comment: How about stubbing? It seems I can do stubbing outside of the specification using Expandos but I'm wondering if there's an official Spock way to do it?